# Eigenvalues of an upper Hessenberg matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition, companion-matrices

I'm interested in calculating the roots of an 11th degree polynom.
To do so, I calculated the $10 \times 10$ companion matrix which eigenvalues are the roots of the polynomial.

Now, the eigenvalues could be real or complex and in my code, I just need real ones. Is there a way to find the real eigenvalues only of an upper Hessenberg matrix (companion matrix) using iterations of the QR algorithm?

Let $A$ be our upper Hessenberg matrix. I tried the following

```
M=A
for i=1:100
[Q,R]=qr(M);
M=R*Q;
end
```

`diag(M)` will converge to `eig(A)` if A is symmetric, if not real eigenvalues exist but complex ones dosen't. I just need real eigenvalues but how to distinguish in `diag(M)` values that the entry correspond to a real eigenvalue?

Comment: Sure, just start applying the $QR$ algorithm.  It'll converge fairly nicely if you start with something upper-hessenberg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, there is no advantage to trying to compute only the real eigenvalues versus just computing them all; they could all be real or all be complex.

Second, the QR algorithm as you've written it converges extremely slowly compared to state-of-the-art implicitly shifted Hessenberg QR. If you use eig() in Matlab, it will use the faster algorithm and almost certainly be faster than your `qr` in a loop.

Comment: the whole point of the Matlab QR is that it puts the matrix into Hessenberg form.  OP is *starting* with such a matrix

Comment: The problem is that i'm porting a Matlab code to gpu, and I need to compute roots of several polynoms in parallel..The rest of the code works only with real roots..Is it possible to implement the shifted QR and retrieve real eigenvalues?

Comment: And I'm sure the Matlab algorithm will take advantage of the fact that it is already upper Hessenberg, since I know that the Lapack code does it.

Comment: Check out the [MAGMA project](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/magma/) that aims to implement linear algebra on the GPU. Edit: MAGMA doesn't support non-symmetric problems. Let me look up this other thing...

Comment: Check out [this paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=6969057).